# Validation on not required field

Tags: angularjs, html

I have three dropdowns to set unique orders value.
Html Code:-

```
<form name="submitForm" ng-submit="save(submitForm.$valid)" novalidate="novalidate">
    <div class="form-group">
     <label>Unique order:</label>   
        <label>First Step</label>
           <select ng-model="myOrder.step[0]" ng-change="checked()">
              <option value="1">1</option>
              <option value="2">2</option>
              <option value="3">3</option>
           </select>

        <label>First Step</label>
           <select ng-model="myOrder.step[1]" ng-change="checked()">
              <option value="1">1</option>
              <option value="2">2</option>
              <option value="3">3</option>
           </select>

        <label>First Step</label>
           <select ng-model="myOrder.step[2]" ng-change="checked()">
              <option value="1">1</option>
              <option value="2">2</option>
              <option value="3">3</option>
           </select>
    </div>

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Save</button>
</form>
```

On these dropdowns I applied a filter. 
Directive Code:-

```
        return {
            restrict: 'EA',
            scope: {},
            controller: function ($scope) {
                $scope.myOrder = {};
                $scope.myOrder.step = [];
            },
            link: function (scope, el, attrs) {
                scope.checked = function() {
                  if (_.uniq(scope.myOrder.step).length !== scope.myOrder.step.length) {
                     scope.notify("error", "Please set unique order value");
                   }
                 };
                scope.save = function(isValid) {
                    if (isValid) {              
                        if (!scope.values) {                                                                              
                  ApiServices.updateOrderSet(scope.myOrder).then(function (response) {
                                    scope.notify('success', response.data);
                                    scope.values = false;
                                });
                        } else {                                        
                   ApiServices.updateAddSet(scope.myOrder).then(function (response) {
                                    scope.notify('success', response.data);
                                });
                        }
                    } else {
                        scope.notify('error', 'There are errors on the form');
                    }
                };
            },
```

What I want is if user set same values on dropdowns i.e., not unique ,then on save button it notifies `scope.notify("error", "Please set unique order value");` also the form doesn't submit. Please note that these are not required fields.I tried `$submitted` too but doesn't work.Can anyone tell me what should I do here to make it work.